Adding outlines for blender model with sharp edges
I've started learning some three.js and blender to achieve the cartoon effect. I've been working on some code to add black outlines to Blender objects. I've based my code on the tutorial I found on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5UllFImvoE), but it struggles with sharp edges. 
I've tried using the "three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/OutlinePass.js" but it only outlines the outer edges of the object. Is there any way I can achieve the outline effect with fragmentShader for sharp edges? Or do I need to change the blender model settings?
export class ObjectRenderer {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Initializing ObjectRenderer...');
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

        this.textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        this.textureLoader.load('./images/background-borderlands.jpg', (texture) => {
            this.scene.background = texture;
        });

        this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
        this.directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
        this.directionalLight.position.set(5, 5, 5).normalize();
        this.scene.add(this.directionalLight);

        this.composer = new EffectComposer(this.renderer);
        this.renderPass = new RenderPass(this.scene, this.camera);
        this.composer.addPass(this.renderPass);

        this.camera.position.z = 5;

        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            const width = window.innerWidth;
            const height = window.innerHeight;
            this.camera.aspect = width / height;
            this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
            this.composer.setSize(width, height);
        });

        
    }

    renderObject(modelPath) {
        const loader = new GLTFLoader();
        loader.load(modelPath, (gltf) => {
            gltf.scene.traverse((child) => {
                if (child.isMesh && child.material instanceof THREE.MeshStandardMaterial) {

                    const thickness = 0.01;
                    const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                        vertexShader: /* glsl */`
                            void main() {
                                vec3 newPosition = position + normal * ${thickness};
                                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1);
                            }
                        `,
                        fragmentShader: /* glsl */`
                            void main() {
                                gl_FragColor = vec4(0,0,0,1);
                            }
                        `,
                        side: THREE.BackSide
                    });
                    
                    const outline = new THREE.Mesh(child.geometry, material);
                    child.add(outline);
                    
                }
            });

            this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
        }, undefined, (error) => {
            console.error('Error loading model:', error);
        });
    }

  
    animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
        this.controls.update();
        this.composer.render();
    }
}

export default ObjectRenderer;

